# ngdbc.jar equivalent Maven repository

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

I am using `ngdbc.jar` to connect Java and HANA. Now I want to build a Web application. So I searched for the equivalent Maven repository but I could not find that one.

I found mostly for the cloud ones and finally found this one:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo-java-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.53.18.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Can any one tell which repository I can use instead of `ngdbc.jar`? Any help is appreciated

Comment: why don't you just include ngdbc.jar directly in your web app?

Comment: How to include the jar in my maven project?

Comment: You can either install it to local repo or just include it from system path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project

Comment: @YohanesGultom Do you know where to get the  ngdbc.jar because I want to check with alternative versions and check.But I could not find it in online.Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAP doesn't allowed redistribution of ngdbc.jar in their TC as mentioned [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3944326). So you won't find any legal one online.

Your only option is to [include the jar from your local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project). Something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

described here here how to deal with the missing ngdbc.jar:

https://github.com/claboran/priceimporter

Answer (score 1):

I tried to  install the jar file as a dependency by

```
install:install-file -Dfile=C:\ngdbc.jar -DgroupId=com.han.driver -DartifactId=hana -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

in Maven which is pretty handy and good way.hope this helps someone dealing with custom jars.